# Disable/enable select

Tags: jquery, html

I have two ul lists and in each list two select boxes. I need to make first select box disable and enable second select box. When first option is chosen second select should be disabled,else enabled. The same goes for a second list.
this is my html:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="select-country">
      <select class="units" id="country">
        <option value="Metres">Metres</option>
        <optgroup label="Evropa">
          <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
          <option value="Fathoms">Fathoms</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Afrika">
          <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Azija">
          <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Severna Amerika">
          <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        </optgroup>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li style="visibility: visible;">
    <label>Destinacija:</label>
    <div class="select-country">
      <select class="units" id="destination">
        <option value="Metres">Metres</option>
        <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        <option value="Fathoms">Fathoms</option>
        <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and this is script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#destination').prop('disabled','disabled').css('opacity','0.5');        
  $('#country').on('change',function(){
    var  choice = $(this).val();
    if(choice == "Metres"){                           
      console.log($('#destination').prop('disabled','disabled').css('opacity','0.5'));
    }else{
      $('#destination').prop('disabled',false).css('opacity','1');
    }
  });
});
```

The code works for two select boxes,but i want one script that works for both list... i put just one list in this question,but the second one is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a common class and use `this` there:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.desti-select').prop('disabled','disabled').css('opacity','0.5');        
  $('.country-select').on('change',function(){
    var choice = $(this).val();
    if(choice == "Metres"){                           
      $(this).closest("ul").find('.desti-select').prop('disabled','disabled').css('opacity','0.5');
    }else{
      $(this).closest("ul").find('.desti-select').prop('disabled',false).css('opacity','1');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="select-country">
      <select class="units country-select" id="country-1">
        <option value="Metres">Metres</option>
        <optgroup label="Evropa">
          <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
          <option value="Fathoms">Fathoms</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Afrika">
          <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Azija">
          <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Severna Amerika">
          <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        </optgroup>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li style="visibility: visible;">
    <label>Destinacija:</label>
    <div class="select-country">
      <select class="units desti-select" id="destination-1">
        <option value="Metres">Metres</option>
        <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        <option value="Fathoms">Fathoms</option>
        <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="select-country">
      <select class="units country-select" id="country-2">
        <option value="Metres">Metres</option>
        <optgroup label="Evropa">
          <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
          <option value="Fathoms">Fathoms</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Afrika">
          <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Azija">
          <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Severna Amerika">
          <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        </optgroup>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li style="visibility: visible;">
    <label>Destinacija:</label>
    <div class="select-country">
      <select class="units desti-select" id="destination-2">
        <option value="Metres">Metres</option>
        <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        <option value="Fathoms">Fathoms</option>
        <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively, you can also use HTML5 `data-*` attributes to do this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.desti-select').prop('disabled','disabled').css('opacity','0.5');        
  $('.country-select').on('change',function(){
    var choice = $(this).val();
    if(choice == "Metres"){                           
      $($(this).data('desti')).prop('disabled','disabled').css('opacity','0.5');
    }else{
      $($(this).data('desti')).prop('disabled',false).css('opacity','1');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="select-country">
      <select class="units country-select" id="country-1" data-desti="#destination-1">
        <option value="Metres">Metres</option>
        <optgroup label="Evropa">
          <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
          <option value="Fathoms">Fathoms</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Afrika">
          <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Azija">
          <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Severna Amerika">
          <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        </optgroup>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li style="visibility: visible;">
    <label>Destinacija:</label>
    <div class="select-country">
      <select class="units desti-select" id="destination-1">
        <option value="Metres">Metres</option>
        <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        <option value="Fathoms">Fathoms</option>
        <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="select-country">
      <select class="units country-select" id="country-2" data-desti="#destination-2">
        <option value="Metres">Metres</option>
        <optgroup label="Evropa">
          <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
          <option value="Fathoms">Fathoms</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Afrika">
          <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Azija">
          <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Severna Amerika">
          <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        </optgroup>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li style="visibility: visible;">
    <label>Destinacija:</label>
    <div class="select-country">
      <select class="units desti-select" id="destination-2">
        <option value="Metres">Metres</option>
        <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        <option value="Fathoms">Fathoms</option>
        <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'd probably use `<select data-dest="#destination">` and `$($(this).data('dest'))` instead of `closest`.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko Yes, that's a good idea too. But that would be supported by the modern HTML5 browsers only right. Okay, I will edit my answer to give that solution too.

Comment: @PravenKumar I'm not sure, `data` seems to be present for a long time already.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko Have a look. Updated. Thanks for the heads up. `:)`

Comment: That is what i need. So simple. Thanks

Comment: @PravenKumar can you look at this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L8mdh1xq/) and tel me what am i doing wrong. I want to change options text,but it changes text for select with id="destination-1" and id="destination-2". i want it to work separately.

Comment: @DejanJankov You are not disabling them at first.

Comment: @PravenKumar thanks for that. But this is problem i have two ul lists and in each list two select boxes. I need to make first select box change options of second select box. When first option is chosen second select should have options of var=one,when socond options of var=two and so on. The same goes for a second list

Comment: for now if i chose option in first select box it changes options in second select box in first list and in second list.